# Como Imprimir varias lineas de texto en forma de columna

Tags: java, android

Estoy imrpimiendo unas lineas en un ticket y necesito que parezcan en forma de columna, aunque en la realidad estoy imprimiendo filas:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <yourClassList.size() ; i++) {
            printables.add(new TextPrintable.Builder().setText(
                    yourClassList.get(i).getDescripcion().substring(0,10)+"   "+
                            yourClassList.get(i).getCantidad()+"  "+
                            yourClassList.get(i).getPrecioUnitario()+"  "+yourClassList.get(i).getPrecioTotal()).setNewLinesAfter(1).build()); 
        }
```

Con el codigo anterior imprimo x cantidad de lineas con la siguiente forma:

```
 JAMON DE PIE    25  15.20  380
 SALCHICHA CO    234  12.2  2854.8
```

Pero quiero que parezcan columnas como las siguientes:

```
 JAMON DE PIE    25  15.20  380
 SALCHICHA CO    234 12.2   2854.8
```

La distorsion se crea por la cantidad de numero de cada cifra.

Estoy usando la libreria Printooth con android

Answer (score 3):

Debes utilizar el tabulador mediante el carácter `"\t"` en lugar de espacios ( `+"   "+` ), de esta forma tus resultados se mostrarán similar a columnas:

```
yourClassList.get(i).getDescripcion().substring(0,10)+"\t"+
                            yourClassList.get(i).getCantidad()+"\t"+
                            yourClassList.get(i).getPrecioUnitario()+"\t"+yourClassList.get(i).getPrecioTotal()
```

para obtener una salida similar a :

```
JAMON DE PIE    25  15.20  380
SALCHICHA CO    234 12.2   2854.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que tu mejor alternativa sería usar un font "mono" donde los caracteres tienen el mismo ancho. Y luego formatear las líneas con `String.format(locale, patrón, variables ...)`.

Con el patrón podes determinar el ancho de cada columna formatear los números, y alinear a derecha o a izquierda.

Respecto a la alternativa de hacerlo con tabuladores tiene el problema de que si los textos varian en el ancho, un texto mas largo puede hacer saltar al próximo tabulado, rompiendo el encolumnado.

[String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.util.Locale-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)
[Formatos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)